# Collapsible Box Script Interfering with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the script needed for the collapsible box to work

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

But the 4th line of code is interfering with my CSS, in terms of backgrounds and font. This community told how to fix the background color with:

```css
body.ui-overlay-a {
    background-color: #dc143c;
}

div.ui-page-theme-a {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Where `text-shadow: none;` being the line of code to remove the blue-ish outlines in my navigation bar (code below), but doesn't remove it anywhere else. I applied this to the `p` and `h4` tags in my CSS but it doesn't apply.

Through trial and error I have found out that line 4 was the reason why it was interfering. Line 4 code (as mentioned above):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

If I remove this, my collapsible box disappears. But if I leave it, I lose my background color and font. Help please and thanks in advance.

Navigation bar, collapsible box code will be provided below. For more reference I have uploaded my file into a free web hoster here.

As you can see, the part where it says "Restaurante etc", it has this really weird shadow to it, the font of the navigation bar is not "Roboto", as mentioned in the CSS code, and when I hover over the "About Us" page it does not use Roboto nor Lato, which were the only two fonts mentioned in my file.

Navigation Bar Content:

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Contacts </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Map </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Reservations </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Online Order </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Navigation Bar CSS:

```css
/* Navigation bar */
.nav {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000000;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;

}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #D3D3D3;
}

.headerBreak {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Collapsible Box Script:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Collapsible Box Content:

```html
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2> MENU // SOUPS </h2>
        <p> Blank </p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2> MENU // BEEF </h2>
        <p> Blank </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to do a hard refresh - there is no text-shadow visible anywhere on that page. It IS visible, but not active (it's overridden by the changes you made) in the CSS.

Comment: I've decided to approach collapsible boxes in a different way using accordions. Thanks for the help ^_^